# Angular AOT error:TypeError: this.compiler.analyzeModulesAsync is not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement angular application using AOT compiler. I followed article https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler.
Hence I downloaded the setup did the files changes, created tsconfig-aot.json on compiling the project using command
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json It throws error

```
TypeError: this.compiler.analyzeModulesAsync is not a function
at CodeGenerator.codegen (/media/arjun/D/Work/TeachingMaterial/anngularJS/angular_aot2/quickstart/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/codegen.js:32:14)
at codegen (/media/arjun/D/Work/TeachingMaterial/anngularJS/angular_aot2/quickstart/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/main.js:13:81)
at Object.main (/media/arjun/D/Work/TeachingMaterial/anngularJS/angular_aot2/quickstart/node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/main.js:106:16)
at main (/media/arjun/D/Work/TeachingMaterial/anngularJS/angular_aot2/quickstart/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/main.js:19:16)
at Object. (/media/arjun/D/Work/TeachingMaterial/anngularJS/angular_aot2/quickstart/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/main.js:35:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
Compilation failed
```

My package.json file dependencies

```
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"systemjs": "0.19.40",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

Node version v7.9.0

OS Ubuntu

Please suggest what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Could you please share your application with [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) (it would be useful to check and help you)?

Comment: I just downloaded my application from https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart and made few minor changes in it as suggested in article  https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the mismatched versions of @angular/compiler-cli and other angular packages. So we suggest you to **install @angular/compiler-cli package in the same version of other angular packages** in your application.

Use "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0" instead of "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.0",